Customise Android phone for someone with Dementia
I have a parent with Dementia, who has always struggled with technology but we need a way of

Calling them
Tracking them
Allow them to make calls

They do not need all the functionality of a smartphone but I am hoping I can setup one in a way that would help them. The Android Find My Device would allow us to find them when they wander off, so the only other functionality I want is to make a call and answer a call, that is it. It needs to be very easy because if they find themselves in some menu somewhere they cannot find there way back, so I want to hide everything else.
I wanted a couple of pictures on the phone they can tap to call that particular person and an easy way to answer an incoming call.
Is there a way I can configure or setup a phone in this way. I am pretty technical (software developer) just don't actually know much about phones. Can I even write some software to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.  We have tried old fashioned non-smart phones but even those are too complicated, they have to open contacts, find the person, press a button to make a call etc, because with dementia they cannot remember any instructions, and that is too much, it needs to be very very intuitive and limited.

Android allows you to change the launcher app which is responsible for the home screen and the app list. There are implementations available for elderly people like https://github.com/itsarjunsinh/elder_launcher

There are other problems to solve too: getting the parent to remember to take the phone with them, and getting them to remember to charge it.

thank you for everyones suggestions, much appreciated

You can customize and Android phone's launcher (home screen).
Such as Simple

Simple Launcher (Big Launcher)*
About this app
A simple interface for Android phone,easy to use,very friendly for old people and minimalist

Or buy them a phone specifically made for them.  They are really cheap and simpler and fewer functions.  As a bonus, they have large buttons.
An example is

